# Exclude class from aar

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I have a "base" library, which provides pure Java code, now I want to create a Android library on top of that. Let's say both libraries have a Log class. When I build the aar and nest it in a project, I am able to choose which Log class I want to import (which I try to prevent, only the Log class from the Android-library should be shown). Is there is a chance to exclude the library when the aar gets build? 
Here is the gradle (I tried a lot, but nothing helped).

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


repositories {
    jcenter()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 9
        versionName "0.0.9"
        project.archivesBaseName = "andcommon"
        project.version = android.defaultConfig.versionName
    }

    packagingOptions {
//        exclude 'res'
    }

//    configurations {
//        compile.exclude group: 'com.pepperonas.jbasx'
//    }
//    sourceSets {
//        main {
//            java {
//                exclude '**/Log.java'
//            }
//        }
//    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }



    buildTypes {
        all {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def outputFile = output.outputFile
            if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.aar')) {
                def fileName = "${archivesBaseName}-${version}.aar"
                output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
                output.outputFile = new File("/home/pepperonas/IdeaProjects/Libraries/Base/testapp/libs", fileName)
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile project(':jbasx')

//    compile files('libs/jbasx-0.0.9.jar')
}
```

Comment: Did you found a solution?